# How to set variable with specified date and time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I searched it a lot but coudn't find any instance of showing how to store the specified time. For example, i need to save time of 15:48 in code in a proper variable (i guess that should be NSDate object). That is needed because i want to hold the exact time to replace the method below with not the time interval since now but my exact specified time to fire notification. Thanks for the help.

```
NSDate *notificationDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5]; 
notification.fireDate  = notificationDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSDateComponents`:

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setHour:15];    // 15:48 from your example
[comps setMinute:48];  // 15:48 from your example
/// also set year, month and day
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
    initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];
[comps release];
```

You can also use NSDateCompnents to read the components from the current date and time - so if you want to set an NSDate to 15:48 today, you would first create an NSDate for now and then extract the day, month and year from it but overwrite the hour and minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSDateComponents to generate an NSDate object. I guess the Apple document is what you want http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDateFormatter) and especially `- (NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)string`

Comment: Only good if you have the date in a string to start with - and then, relatively brittle and slow. NSDateFormatter is good for reading in from external resources (server time, user input) but not actually setting dates from code.